# One association class for two associations in Visual Paradigm - how?

Tags: class, associations, uml, visual-paradigm

I would like to ask if it's possible to connect one association class with two associations between two classes?

[image: association class]

Right now association class WypozyczenieSprzetu is connected only with 'Oddaje' association. I would like to connect WypozyczenieSprzetu with both 'Oddaje' i 'Wypozycza' but Visual Paradigm does not let me to do it. Do you know any idea on how to do it?

EDIT:
translated to english...
[image]

Comment: Can you translate the class names and association names to English?

Comment: done. Its a part of simple system for ski school and rental. Client rents and gives back equipment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Source: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/
>
> **11.5.3 Structured Classifiers → Associations → Semantics → Association Classes**
>
> An AssociationClass is a declaration of an Association that has a set of Features of its own. An AssociationClass is both an Association and a Class, and preserves the static and dynamic semantics of both...

The way I read the above is that either

1. you can connect the `association class` to only one line in the diagram
2. or you need to use [N-ary Association](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#arity)
3. or you need something like this:

   [image]